# Работа с двумя базами MySQL одновременно [Решено]

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, запрос, база-данных

Здравствуйте, хотел оптимизировать запросы в две разных БД на сайте, и проблема встала в селектах (скорее всего еще где-то но я пока споткнулся тут) , я изучаю php пол года и решил заняться оптимизацией, вот часть моего скрипта для работы с базой:
БД-1 локальна
БД-2 на другом сервере

```
$GLOBALS['db1'] = mysql_pconnect($db_host, $db_login, $db_pass, true) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name, $GLOBALS['db1']) or die(mysql_error());

$GLOBALS['db2'] = mysql_pconnect($db2_host, $db2_login, $db2_pass, true) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db2_name, $GLOBALS['db2']) or die(mysql_error());

function db_q($db, $query)
{
    mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"', $GLOBALS["db$db"]);
    return mysql_query($query, $GLOBALS["db$db"]);
}

function db_ar($in)
{
    return mysql_fetch_array($in);
}

function db_as($in)
{
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($in);
}

function db_obj($in)
{
    return mysql_fetch_object($in);
}
```

Возможно с $GLOBALS глупое решение? но оно работает, и другого я пока не нашел,
после всего этого я пишу вот такой код

```
$db2 = db_q(2, "SHOW DATABASES");
while (($r2 = db_ar($db2)) != false) {
    print_r($r2);
}
$db = db_q(1, "SHOW DATABASES");
while (($r = db_ar($db)) != false) {
    print_r($r);
}
```

и все логично работает и не запинается выдает 2 массива данных, но проблема встает другая когда я делаю "селект в селекте":

```
$db = db_q(1, "SHOW DATABASES");
while (($r = db_ar($db)) != false) {
    $db2 = db_q(2, "SHOW DATABASES");
    while (($r2 = db_ar($db2)) != false) {
        print_r($r2);
    }
    print_r($r);
}
```

результат с print_r($r2); должен повторяться столько раз сколько баз в первой БД, а на выходе я получаю все дазы из первой БД, но при этом всего лишь один раз результаты из второй БД, при этом если брать сначала данные из дальнего сервера и внутри этого массива выводить данные из локального то все работает правильно

Comment: кашмар. во первых расширение mysql устарело, ещё до этого устарела идея использовать pconnect, по поводу вообще идеи как это делается я даже не знаю что сказать. почему бы вам не давать вашей db_q ссылку на базу ? ну или если уж делать с такими странностями, то сделайте  класс который будет цеплять и запоминать коннекшены к базе.

Comment: да с классами решение я знаю там все работает, хотелось бы без них обойтись и pconnect можно не использовать

Comment: да зачем вам вообще такой монстр ?

Comment: всё ядро было написано на классах, стал переписывать на функции все нормально только в запросах спотыкается, в старой версии было два класса для двух коннектов к БД, но тесты показали что ядро на функциях работает быстрее чем на классах

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил сам проблемы в конфигах)

```
$GLOBALS['db_config_1'] = mysql_pconnect($db_host, $db_login, $db_pass, true) or     die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_name, $GLOBALS['db_config_1']) or die(mysql_error());

$GLOBALS['db_config_2'] = mysql_pconnect($db2_host, $db2_login, $db2_pass, true) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db2_name, $GLOBALS['db_config_2']) or die(mysql_error());

function db_q($db, $query)
{
    mysql_query('SET NAMES "utf8"', $GLOBALS["db_config_$db"]);
    return mysql_query($query, $GLOBALS["db_config_$db"]);
}
```